# Finding unknowns inside integration of exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I have this equation:

$$\int_1^N a \ e^{-bx} dx = k$$

, where $N, k$ are constants. Is it possible to find the values of $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the above equation?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I'm not sure how to move forward. I thought first to get rid of the integration by differentiating both sides, but this will make $k$ zero

Comment: Please become aware of what you have in front of you. Both sides are numbers - not functions that you can differentiate. The integral is very, very simple to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, all I have to do is to perform the definite integration:

$$\int_1^Nae^{-bx}dx = \frac{a(e^{-b}-e^{-bN})}{b}$$

and then set $b$ equals to 1 or any other constant

$$\frac{a(e^{-1}-e^{-N})}{b} = k$$

and solve for $a$

$$a = \frac{kb}{e^{-1}-e^{-N}}$$